# SpreadsheetApp unable to openById with Id returned by DriveApp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a script that:

1. Reads a value from one spreadsheet
2. Searches a google drive folder for a 2nd spreadsheet file with a name that matches that value from the 1st spreadsheet and gets the id for that file
3. Uses the id to open the 2nd spreadsheet, read some data, and write that data to the 1st spreadsheet

The script does return an Id, but I get the error: "Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp." I checked the id returned in my Logger.log to see if it matches the file I wanted the script to find, and the ids didn't match. I also checked to see if the Url matched the spreadsheet I wanted, and they did match. Unfortunately, when I tried the openByUrl method I got the same error.

So somehow, the script seems to be finding the right spreadsheet, but is not able to open it.
Here is my code

```js
function getUnitMap() {

  //Create search key using module name 
  var moduleName = ss.getSheetByName("Select Module/Agenda").getRange("j17").getValue();
  var searchFor = 'title contains "' + moduleName + ' Unit Map"';
  Logger.log(searchFor);

  //Use search key to find file in google drive folder 
  var dApp = DriveApp;
  var folder = dApp.getFolderById("1Bhv_yQ6bsDmIjfO5yLsxu61vyEPjL8zj");
  var files = folder.searchFiles(searchFor);
  var fileIds = [];
  var fileUrls = [];

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    fileIds.push(file.getId());
    fileUrls.push(file.getUrl());
  }

  Logger.log(fileIds);
  Logger.log(fileUrls);

  //Write data from searched for file to original spreadsheet 
  var srcSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileIds);
  var srcSheet = srcSs.getSheetByName("Curriculum Map");
  var srcValues = srcSheet.getRange(20, 1, srcSheet.getLastRow(), srcSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Unit Map");
  targetSheet.getRange().setValues(srcValues);
}
```

I'm wondering if this issue might be partially due to the fact that the folder I'm searching through is located in a shared drive. Would there be a way to change my code to reflect that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var srcSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileIds);` openById requires a single id not an array of id's if there is just one id then it should be `fileIds[0]`

Comment: The same thought had occurred to me too, but I tried the fileIds[0] and it returned the same error.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't find anything with your search.  I recommend that you use the debugger  and single step through the programming while examining all of the variables.

Comment: I will definitely try that! However, my search did actually find a file. My Logger.log showed an id, and when I copy and pasted the corresponding url into my browser, it did give me the file my script was trying to find. But  I will for sure give the debugger a try. Thank you!